# My username and password dont work on SHH Trixbox

Tags: linux, ssh, root, linux-distributions

I have a Trixbox Linux instaled (based on Asterisk distribution). I can acces the console normally with my root account.

Its very simple, restart my machine, type login: root and password ************* and finish.

But, I can access SSH of this machine with the same account.

I connect in my server using port 22, the server request my credential, I type root and password ****************. This return "Password Invalid".

Can anybody help me associate my root account with the SSH account?

Comment: I try PermitRootLogin yes, but it dont work. I see this tip on
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/allow-root-account-to-use-ssh-openssh/